# Find the minimum value of $\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a+c)} + \frac{1}{c^3 (a+b)} $

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c $ be positive reals such that $abc=1$. Find the minimum value of $$Q = \frac{1}{a^3(b+c)}  + \frac{1}{b^3(a+c)} + \frac{1}{c^3 (a+b)} $$

My attempt:

Let $P = 2(ab + ba + bc)$.  Then $PQ > \dfrac{1}{a^2} + \dfrac{1}{b^2} + \dfrac{1}{c^2} \geq  3 $, by AM-GM inequality.

Also, $P = 2(ab + ba + bc) = 2(\dfrac{1}{c} + \dfrac{1}{b} + \dfrac{1}{a}) \geq 6 $, by AM-GM inequality.

$P(1,1,1) = 6 $ and $Q(1,1,1) = \frac{3}{2}.$ Could anyone advise me how to show absolute minimum of $Q$ is $\frac{3}{2}$ ?  Hints will suffice, thank you.